# Encryption: turning a string into 4x4 matrix and padding with character "A" so it is divisible by 16

Tags: java, encryption, padding

I'm working on an encryption program that takes a string input then goes through a vigenere cipher and gives an output. I need help with creating a method that takes that output, turns it into 4x4 matrices and then pads the remaining characters with "A's" so that its length is divisible by 16.

Example:

```
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx

xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxAA
```

Currently I have:

```
public static String padding(String text, final String key)
{
    String res = "";
    char[][] a = new char[4][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            a[i][j] = text.charAt(4 * i + j);
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Can anyone give any advice or show me some code of what you would do?

Comment: The method `padding()` returns a single `String` - should it contain all the matrices with newlines etc.? Also, what is `key` for?

Comment: In a previous part of the program, "key" is used as part of the vigenere cipher to decrypt the input string

example:

Key: SIMPLEEXAMPLEKEY

Input text: ENCRYPTTHISMESSAGEUSINGTHEALGORITHMDESCRIBEDBELOW

Output text: WVOGJTXQHUHXICWYYMGHTRKQHQPWKYVGLPYSPWGOINTOFOPMO

Comment: yes correct, it should return the "output" but in 4x4 matrices and have "A's" padded on to the ends if needed

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a different order from what you are doing.  Pad with A first.  Do this by taking the length modulo 16, subtract that from 16, and add that many As.  Then create your 4 x 4 array and simply Buffer.BlockCopy the 1-dimensional array into the 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

As WDS mentioned, you should pad before formatting the text into matrices. Also you don't need the `char` array, you can just use `StringBuilder` and append substrings of the text as needed. And according to what you posted, the padding method doesn't need `key`.

```
private static final String PADDING = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

public static String pad(String text) {

    int padCount = (16 - text.length() % 16) % 16; // the second % makes sure that if the string length is divisible by 16, we don't pad it at all
    String paddedText = text + PADDING.substring(0, padCount);

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < paddedText.length(); i += 16) {
        for (int j = i; j < i + 16; j += 4) {
            result.append(paddedText.substring(j, j + 4));
            result.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        result.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```